# Command "make:factory" is not defined Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Could n't create a factory via artisan command to seeed the data in a database

Command "make:factory" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?

```
  make:auth

  make:command

  make:controller

  make:event

  make:job

  make:listener

  make:mail

  make:middleware

  make:migration

  make:model

  make:notification

  make:policy

  make:provider

  make:request

  make:seeder

  make:test
```

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? the version you are using most likely does not have that command (considering you have the `make:auth` command still)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You need to use `make:seeder` to seed data to database.

laravel has some really good documentation on this as well.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding

Comment: I had manually created a factory file under factories. It works.
After that, just ran the seed command.